# Is it possible to programmatically change GPIO pins voltage?

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I recently bought RPi 4 equipped with fan which I connected to GPIO pins 4 and 6. It's not so quiet so I want to write simple app which will be checking temperature each 5 or 10 seconds and adjust voltage of pin 4. I wonder if there is any way to change voltage from software level? It can be some command line tool or config change, or whatever. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pin 4 is connected to the 5V power rail.  It will always be 5V.

If you want to vary the voltage you will need external circuitry - probably at least a diode, a transistor, and a couple of resistors.  You could then use a GPIO to switch the transistor on and off (the transistor would in turn switch 5V on and off to the fan).  You could vary the effective fan voltage by using PWM on the GPIO and varying the dutycycle.  The higher the dutycycle the higher the effective voltage.